# java BigInteger conversion algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, biginteger

BigInteger from Java stores number as array of "unsigned integers" (it is array of integers, but they store information in 32-bit system and later cast it to long and make operation).

How do they convert from decimal system to base 32-bit system? What is the algorithm?

I was reading sources and I don't understand it. I see they split numbers to 10 digit String (integer can handle 1_000_000_000), but what next?
Deviding by 2? or 2^32 (4294967296)?

Thank you for help to understand it.

Comment: Who said they were storing this information in 32 bits?

Comment: `convert from decimal system to base 32-bit` are you asking how to convert a base 10 number into a base 2 (binary) number? Or about floating point representations? Question is a bit unclear of what you're asking

Comment: I am asking how the String is converted into BigInteger internal represenation (base 32-bit)

Comment: There is no "base 32-bit" in BigInteger (or anywhere). Internally numbers are represented by bits, and BigInteger just uses an int array to add more bits to our "number" if needed

Comment: I agree that there is an array of integers that represents bits, but later they operate on whole integers (cast to long), so they use base 32-bit system.
Anyway, how do they convert String to this big array of bits ???

Comment: No, they truncate to fit the number into either 32 or 64 bits for ints or longs, as necessary.

Comment: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#l466

Comment: @Makoto: look at the sources. BigInteger uses an array of 32 bit integers (treated as unsigned) to store the bits of the magnitude. The sign is an extra member.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis:  That'd imply that there is *at least* 32 bits.

Comment: @Makoto: not for zero. But otherwise they are storing the bits in an array of (unsigned) 32 bit integers. The question seems to be: how do they convert text to binary. Well, that is not so complicated.

Comment: They simply read each digit and process that to form the final BigInteger result. See my answer. Now they could do this in chunks of 9 (not: 10) digits, or for longs even in chunks of 19 digits, but AFAIK, they don't do that.

Comment: You need to look up multi-precision radix conversion. It isn't as simple as you are being misinformed here.

Answer (score -1):

For very large numbers, perhaps a tricky divide-and-conquer algorithm is used, but otherwise, it is done like for integers:

1. Set the intermediate result (a BigInteger) to value BigInteger.ZERO.
2. read the sign (if there is any) and remember it
3. read a digit
4. using the given numeric base (radix, 2..36), convert the digit to binary, e.g. in base 10, `'9'` is converted to 9, in base 16, `'A'` is converted to 10, etc.
5. Multiply the intermediate result by the base and add the value of the digit, so if base is 10, multiply the intermediate result by 10 and add the 9 you just read.
6. Repeat from point 2 until the entire string is read
7. Set the sign
8. Clean up and if necessary, remove leading zeroes, etc.
9. Return the intermediate BigInteger as function result.

The loop works like this:

```
number: 1234 (base 10)
intermediate x = 0
read digit = 1: x = x * 10 + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
read digit = 2: x = x * 10 + 2 = 10 + 2 = 12
read digit = 3: x = x * 10 + 3 = 120 + 3 = 123
read digit = 4: x = x * 10 + 4 = 1230 + 4 = 1234

the same number in base 16:
read digit = 1: x = x * 16 + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
read digit = 2: x = x * 16 + 2 = 16 + 2 = 18 (= 0x12)
read digit = 3: x = x * 16 + 3 = 288 + 3 = 291 (= 0x123)
read digit = 4: x = x * 16 + 4 = 4656 + 4 = 4660 (= 0x1234)
```

Comment: Neither this nor the other answer addresses the issue of multiple-precision conversion. It isn't as simple as represented here.

Answer (score -1):

To be correct, Java stores BigInteger as array of int (Java doesn't have unsigned int).

You have a number value, and you can store it in any base: base 2 (binary), base 10 (decimal), base 16 (Hex) or base 100. Java call it radix.

In whatever base, that value remains the same. for example 12(decimal)=1100(binary)=C(Hex)=C(Base 100).
To store efficiently, Java should choose a very big base to:

- Nearly fit to an int max value (if less than that too much, you will be wasting memory. Should take nearly all the bits of an int into account)
- Easily add digits of that base using int without overflow (should be less than or equal to half of 2^31)

That's why they choose a base 10^9 to store that.

Java actuall uses an general algorithm to convert any radix other than decimal conversion, that involves calculation of how many digits (of the given radix) per int. But for simplicity, I take what is going for decimal, the algorithm is:

```
 int mag[];
 BigInteger(String decimalDigits){
    mag= new int[size of array enough to store value];
    cut decimalDigits into chunks of 9 digits (the first chunk may have less than 9 digits)
    parse that chunks into integer and save into mag array (in big endian order) 
 }
```

Comment: Everybody calls it 'radix'. Neither this nor the other answer addresses the issue of multiple-precision conversion. It isn't as simple as represented here.

Comment: @user207421: did you really read the question? Quincy asked the algorithm to convert decimal to store value to an int.